# Как происходит выделение памяти при запуске бинарного файла в Linux?

Tags: linux, память, binary

Привет!
Как Linux выделяет память под процесс при запуске бинарного файла?

Например, если у меня файл размером 100М, то значит ли это, что при запуске он весь перечитается системой, целиком разместится в памяти/виртуальной памяти и выполнится оттуда (не обращаясь к диску)?
Либо же в файле есть некая секция, которая описывает необходимые ресурсы для запуска файла и по мере выполнения определенные части файла подгружаются с диска в память?

Comment: 1. [страничная память](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) 2. [How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не вдаваться в подробности, то ядро читает заголовки и кое-какую служебную информацию из ELF'а, а затем отображает некоторые секции в виртуальную память процесса, в частности .text (с «атрибутами» r-x), .rodata (r--) и .data (rw-) ). Если какие-то страницы уже загружены в кеше страниц (например файл остался в нём после обычного чтения/записи), то они сразу подключаются к процессу; если нет, то они будут загружены только при первом обращении (см. далее). После этого управление передаётся точке входа и процесс начинает работать. Далее, как только процесс обращается к странице, не загруженной в память, возникает страничное прерывание, которое обрабатывается ядром. Оно приостанавливает процесс и загружает необходимую страницу с диска и/или создаёт её отображение из виртуальной памяти в физическую.

В реальности большинство исполняемых файлов слинкованы динамические. Поэтому кроме них самих аналогичным образом подгружаются их библиотеки, правда отображение происходит не по инициативе самого ядра, а динамического линкера (/lib/ld-linux*.so.*) из юзерспейса. При этом ro-данные и код библиотек остаются общими для всех процессов.